# Generate custom start and end of months in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I'm facing an issue while working with custom dates in T-SQL, we have a client that works with a different methodology of `start` and `end` of his month, instead of the default day `01` to start the month and ending in `31`, `30` or `29`, it's month start at day `26` and ends at `25` of the next month.

E.g., how usually is:

```
select sum(sales) as sales
from sales
where salesDate between '2020-09-01' and '2020-09-30'
-- or left(salesDate,7) = '2020-09'
```

Client custom month:

```
select sum(sales) as sales
from sales
where salesDate between '2020-08-26' and '2020-09-25' -- for setember
```

So, for this need, I have to calculate how many sales this client did from january until now, month per month, with this custom way... how can I do that?

Example of the query result I want to perform with this month determination:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty awful situation.  One method is to construct the first date of the month based on the rules:

```
select mon, sum(sales) as sales
from sales s cross apply
     (values (case when day(salesdate) >= 26 
                   then dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(salesdate), month(salesdate), 1))
                   else datefromparts(year(salesdate), month(salesdate), 1)
     ) v(mon)
where v.mon >= '2020-01-01'
group by v.mon;
```

I would recommend adding the fiscal month column as a persisted computed column in the `salesDate` table so you can add an index and not have to worry about the computation.

Or, better yet, add a `calendar` table where you can look up the fiscal month for any (reasonable) date.